# Kotlin: get the data inside a <center> with Jsoup

Tags: android, kotlin, jsoup

i have this HTML

```
<table class="table">

       <tr >
         <th colspan="3" ><center>2019-01-01<br>Some Text  </center></th>
       </tr>
```

i need get **2019-01-01**, i try this in Kotlin:

```
var table = doc.select("table.table")[1]
            var rows = table.select("tr")
            for (row in rows) {
                val th = row.select("th")
                if (th.attr("colspan")=="3"){
                    val date= th.select("center")
                }
```

but this get all the data, how can i just extract what's inside the `<center>` and before `<br>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to extract the text before the `<br>`, you can split it:

```
val date = th.select("center").html().split("<br>").first()
```

This grabs the entire `<center>` tag, gets the html representation, splits it using `<br>` as a delimiter, and then gets the `first()` value (the left hand side).